# Linux - mount command returns zero/0 but not working

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mount, automounting

Sounds strange, I have a shell script that it gets trigger by *udev rules*, to mount attached USB device to the system file tree. The script runs when an usb device attaches to system, so the rules seems to be fine. I monitor how the script progress by syslog, and it also goes fine, and even *mount command* returns zero, and it says:

```
 root[1023]: mount: /dev/sda1 mounted on /media/partitionlabel.
```

But at the end the device is not mounted, it is not listed in */etc/mtab - /proc/mounts - findmnt - mount*. and if I run *umount* on device, it also says, the device is not mounted.

However If I run the script manually as a root from terminal, then it works perfect and device gets mount, but not when it runs by *udev*.

I've added 8 second sleep time to the start of the script, to make sure it's not a timing problem and also removed number from rules file name to make sure *udevd* would put the new rules at the bottom of rules queue, and script would run after other system rules, but no success.

#### The syslog:

(right after the device attached)

```
kernel: usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using dwc_otg
kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: Mass Storage
kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
kernel: usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 24DCF568
kernel: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 1968128 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 GB/961 MiB)
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
kernel:  sda: sda1
kernel: sda: p1 size 1968126 extends beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
kernel:  sda: sda1
kernel: sda: p1 size 1968126 extends beyond EOD, truncated
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
root[1004]: /usr/local/sbin/udev-auto-mount.sh - status: started to automount sda1
root[1019]: /usr/local/sbin/udev-auto-mount.sh - status: Device Label is partitionlabel and Filesystem is vfat.
root[1021]: /usr/local/sbin/udev-auto-mount.sh - status: mounting the device sda1 by filesystem vfat to /media/partitionlabel.
root[1023]: mount: /dev/sda1 mounted on /media/partitionlabel.
root[1024]: /usr/local/sbin/udev-auto-mount.sh status: mount command proceed for vfat, retval is 0
root[1025]: /usr/local/sbin/udev-auto-mount.sh - status: succeed!
```

### Configs:

#### /etc/udev/rules.d/local-rules:

The defined rule in *udev* is:

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/local-rules
ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb",     ACTION=="add",  ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition",      \
          RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/udev-automounter.sh %k $ENV{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}"
```

#### udev-auto-mount.sh

The script starts by another script which defined in the udev rule. 
It so straight, it makes *mount point* directory and mounts the usb device to the mount point using its file system type and some regular options. I've added "-v" option to the mount command to be more verbose and also redirected all outputs to syslog, so I can see how it runs, but it not says too much.

```
#!/bin/sh
## /usr/local/sbin/udec-auto-mount.sh
##

logger -s "$0 - status: started to automount ${1}"
DEVICE=$1
sleep 8 

#...
#...
# Checking inputs, getting filesystem type (ID_FS_TYPE), partition label
# (ID_FS_LABEL) and ...

mkdir "/media/${ID_FS_LABEL}"


logger -s "$0 - status: mounting the device ${DEVICE} by filesystem ${ID_FS_TYPE} to /media/${ID_FS_LABEL}."
case $ID_FS_TYPE in
    vfat)   mount -v -t vfat -o sync,noatime,nosuid,nodev /dev/${DEVICE} "/media/${ID_FS_LABEL}" 2>&1 | logger
        let retVal=$?
        logger -s "$0 status: mount command proceed for vfat, retval is ${retVal}"
        ;;

    *)  mount -v -t auto -o sync,noatime /dev/${DEVICE} "/media/${ID_FS_LABEL}"
        ;;
esac
if [ ${retVal} -eq 0 ]; then
    logger -s "$0 - status: succeed!"
    exit 0
else
    logger -s "$0 Error: unable to mount the device ${DEVICE}, retval is ${retVal}"
    rmdir "/media/${ID_FS_LABEL}"
fi

exit 0
```

### Maybe it helps:

Sometimes, after the script fails to mount the USB device, when I detach the device, some error come to syslog like:

```
kernel: usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 11
systemd-udevd[143]: error: /dev/sda: No such file or directory
systemd-udevd[977]: inotify_add_watch(7, /dev/sda, 10) failed: No such file or directory
```

## Edit:

This is 'mount' version:

```
$ mount -V:
mount from util-linux 2.27.1 (libmount 2.27.0: assert, debug)
```

Comment: FWIW. In `udevadm monitor -kup` I can't see ID_FS_LABEL.

Comment: It may not be available for all media devices, mostly for those that their partition label have not been set, so the variable may be empty. But it is one of standard udev variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330094/udev-rule-to-mount-disk-does-not-work/330156#answer-330156).

Actually the problem were came from `systemd-udevd` which succeeded original `udev`. The `systemd-udevd` creates it's own mirror of root file system, when the 'udev' rule mount the device, it gets mounted and is accessible from:

```
/proc/{PID of systemd-udevd service}/root/{path to mount point}
```

but it is not visible from main root filesystem `/`.

`archlinux`'s wiki ([here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev)) suggests:

> Warning: To mount removable drives, do not call mount from `udev` rules. In case of FUSE filesystems, you will get Transport endpoint not connected errors. Instead, you could use `udisks` that handles automount correctly or to make mount work inside udev rules, copy `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service` and replace `MountFlags=slave` to `MountFlags=shared`.[3] Keep in mind though that `udev` is not intended to invoke long-running processes.

***Solution:***

I copied `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service` to the `/etc/systemd/sytem/` directory and replaced `MountFlags=slave` by `MountFlags=shared`. then restarted the system, and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 13):

On a system with systemd, this problem can be encountered when you reformat the partition and try to mount it back.

I moved a disk from encryption to unencrypted, causing systemd’s generated `mnt-disk`.mount to (where mnt-disk is mount path from /etc/fstab) to refer the old path that didn’t exist any more, causing `mount` to go haywire.

Just doing `systemctl daemon-reload` and then doing the mount makes things work.

Comment: My torment ends now. Spent an hour scratching my head as to why I could mount my new volume everywhere except where I wanted it to be.

Comment: Thought I was going crazy, now laughing that it was something so simple.

Comment: Legend! It worked! In my case I executed systemctl daemon-reload. Thanks.

Comment: @Bevilaqua: good catch.

Comment: Also happened on my raspberry pi where a USB drive listed in `/etc/fstab` is plugged into another port and the kernel switches the device from, say, `/dev/sdb2` -> `/dev/sdc2`. This answer resolves that.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence

```
mount ... | logger
rc=$?
```

isn't working as you expect: The return value of a pipe is the return value of the last element in that pipe.

```
$> false | true; echo $?
0
```

If you use bash, try `PIPESTATUS`:

```
$> false | true; echo $? ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
0 1
$> true | false; echo $? {PIPESTATUS[0]}
1 0
```

`PIPESTATUS` is a array variable. Details in the man page of bash. Other shells might have something similar to `PIPESTATUS`

Comment: Good point, but it not seems to be the main problem, as the "mount" itself says device mounted, while it is not.